# Is it possible to eliminate these boundary terms in an integration by parts?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I have a doubt in the first passage of equation (2.5) below ([full work](https://sciences.ucf.edu/math/yqi/wp-content/uploads/sites/24/2017/04/Q-ProcRoyEdinburgh-98.pdf))

[image]

The author is studying the behavior of the PDE $u_t - \Delta(u^m) = |x|^{\sigma}u^p$. After defining $w_l(t)$ it performs the differentiation at $t$

$$ \dfrac{dw_l}{dt} = \int_{\Omega} u_t \varphi_l dx= \int_{\Omega}[\Delta(u^m) \varphi_l + |x|^{\sigma}u^p \varphi_l ]dx$$

Now I don't understand how he got only the expression $\int_{\Omega} u^m \Delta \varphi_l dx$, because even if he performed integration by parts, he should generate a boundary term in the unit sphere, since $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_1$ and I see no reason for $\varphi_l$ to vanish in $\partial \Omega$, as its support is the ball of radius $2$. Does anyone have a hunch what the author might have done to eliminate the boundary terms? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Notice that the author is using $\varphi_l$ with $l>1$, so the function is constant on $\partial\Omega$. This eliminates the boundary term containing $\frac{\partial \varphi_l}{\partial n}$, but there is another term containing $\varphi_l\frac{\partial}{\partial n}(u^m)$ which still seems to remain since $\varphi_l$ is identically $1$ on $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: Additionally, this is an great case for using $\ell$ instead of $l$.

Comment: @whpowell96 this is exactly the problem, because I think you should use integration by parts in the ring $\overline{B(0, R)} \setminus B(0,1)$ and let $R$ tend to infinity. The boundary is divided into two parts, the sphere of radius R and the unit sphere. On the sphere of radius R $\varphi_l$ it eventually vanishes, so the terms on the unit sphere remain

Comment: the boundary terms are $\int_{\mathbb{S}^1} \varphi_l \nabla u^m \cdot \nu dS - \int_{\mathbb{S}^1} u^m \nabla \varphi_l \cdot \nu dS$. The second term cancels out, but the first one really is a mystery.